# Having trouble sharing a ClickOnce app through fileshare

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

Every time I publish my game and move it to a flash drive, it works fine, however, whenever I put the published game into my dropbox folder and attempt to access it from another computer (a Macbook with Windows 7 installed on it) It takes a while to verify application requirements and then if gives me the error: Application Download did not succeed with the following log:

```
    PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.1.7600.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.1
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

    SOURCES
Deployment url          :                                                                                     file:///C:/Users/Muhammad/Downloads/Tier%20Tactical%200.0.5%20(1)/Tier%20Tactical%200.0.5/T        ier%20Tactical%202A.application
Deployment Provider url     : http://logisys-pc/Tier%20Tactical%202A/Tier%20Tactical%202A.application

    ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the              log.
* Activation of C:\Users\Muhammad\Downloads\Tier Tactical 0.0.5 (1)\Tier Tactical 0.0.5\Tier Tactical 2A.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading http:///Tier Tactical 2A/Tier Tactical 2A.application did not succeed.
    + Unable to connect to the remote server
    + A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.2.21:80
```

...It goes on for a while and reiterates what we already know, that there is a connection issue

Some sort of connection issue, in rare cases, I CAN get it started, though briefly, once it does this however, it works fine.

Comment: I haven't actually used XNA or ClickOnce, so it's possible I don't know what I'm talking about.  That said, it's trying to connect to 192.168.2.21, which is an internal ip address, which sounds wrong to me.  What is at that IP?  Is it some sort of proxy or DNS server?

Comment: I actually, don't know why thats there, I've tried everything else